# JUnit - assertFalse does not except == Operator?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am currently writing junit tests for my program.

One of my tests updated an existing product. Here`s the code:

```
@Test
public void testUpdate(){
    Produkt p = new Produkt(1, "apple", "food", true, 2.00, false, true);
    assertFalse(handler.updateProdukt(p)==0);;  
}
```

but eclispe always says:

> The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) void, int

if I write null nothing changes...

Is there a possibility to test whether the updatedProdukt is null or not?

I really appreaciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is `void`. It returns nothing and thus the return value cannot be used in assignments or expressions.

Has nothing to do with jUnit or Eclipse.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
handler.updateProdukt(p);
assertEquals("has been updated", theNewExpectedValue,  p.getSomeValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Its more than like that

```
handler.updateProdukt(p)
```

does not return any value, you need to change the signature to

```
int handler.updateProdukt(p)
```

Comment: @maximus You are testing if the method returns 0 but you have declared your method to return void. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `updateProdukt` method returns void. Change it to return something e.g. a `boolean` or an `int`, then you can use it in an `assert`.

The question is: what is `updateProdukt` doing and what do you wish to test? If it is updating the specified product then you should return a `boolean` (true or false) to indicate whether the specified product was updated successfully. Alternatively, return the `Product` which was updated or null if no product was updated.

Comment: so it is not possible to test if the updateProdukt is null or not?

Answer (score 0):

What does your `updateProdukt()` return? Isn't is returning void?

You need to return something from updateProdukt() to be able to use == operator.

Comment: so is there a different Method to test a void Method through unit testing?

Comment: you want to test if the update has actually updated things (by checking the product)

Comment: Unless you define what you are trying to test, it would be difficult to say. If you are verifying if the product updation was successful or not, then return a boolean to indicate it succeeded so you could simply do `assertTrue(handler.updateProdukt(p))`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code if returns int or Strings or Long value.

```
assertFalse(handler.updateProdukt(p).equals(0));
```